# How do I revert a single line in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, version-control

Say I have this:

[Code snippet with changed lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w13Uj.png)

How do I only revert a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

[Eclipse right click revert line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlP39.png)

Right click on the line number with the change, and then choose "Revert Line".